# Testing VS Code extension with npm

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For testing my visual studio code extension I need to open a specific folder.

I've inserted the folder path into the `args` property of `Launch Test` Configuration as explained [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/testing-extensions#_launch-tests-configuration):

```
    {
        "name": "Extension Tests",
        "type": "extensionHost",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
        "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/../../RIOT", "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}", "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceRoot}/out/test" ],
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/out/test/**/*.js" ],
        "preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
    }
```

This works fine if I manually open VS Code and start the test with `Debug: Start (F5)`.

But I want to run tests in batch mode with `npm test` and this does not work.

How to configure the folder under test when using `npm test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the folder under test with `CODE_TESTS_WORKSPACE` environment variable:

```
> export CODE_TESTS_WORKSPACE=whatever_folder
> npm test
```